# Cannot drop or access any database in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, google-cloud-platform, bitnami

When I want to access whatever database in phpmyadmin,the error will shown

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evO88.png)

```
SELECT MAX(version) FROM `myDataBase`.`pma__tracking` WHERE `db_name` = 'myDataBase'  AND `table_name` = ''  AND FIND_IN_SET('DROP DATABASE',tracking) > 0
```

I am using bitnami LAMP in my GCP and therefore I don't know how to reinstall/reconfigure phpmyadmin

I tried execute `$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin` in my terminal but it return :

```
dpkg-query: package 'phpmyadmin' is not installed and no information is available
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: phpmyadmin is not installed
```

in addiction the error shown in other way,

```
Error

SQL query: DocumentationEdit Edit


SELECT `comment`
            FROM `myDataBase`.`pma__column_info`
            WHERE db_name     = 'performance_schema'
                AND table_name  = ''
                AND column_name = '(db_comment)'
MySQL said: Documentation

#1146 - Table 'myDataBase.pma__column_info' doesn't exist
```

Comment: This error says that you don't have `phpmyadmin` but your are trying to reconfigure it

Comment: Can you show the error message which you get in PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: @Neodan I updated the image , plz click to see

Comment: @l.g.karolos but it is installed in my machine ... Is it just execute the command without any setting?

Comment: @MoMoWongHK The error message says that you is trying to perform operations on table which does not exists. Are you sure that you connected to the right database and/or you have all necessary permissions?

Comment: @Neodan It was worked before I imported database from a .sql file. Then the phpmyadmin cannot access another database . Somehow I found is it required to pre-execute 'create_tables.sql' before import an database from source ?

Comment: Can you show us your config.inc.php, obfuscating sensitive details like eventual passwords?

Comment: @MarcDelisle please see the updated error msg for more information

Comment: So in your config.inc.php, the 'pmadb' directive is set to 'myDataBase' but this database does not contain the required tables (in fact I don't see this database in your list of databases in the screenshot). That's why there are error messages. More details in https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#phpmyadmin-configuration-storage.